# In flutter How to make the inner widget with pan gesture will not conflict with PageView

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-pageview

I have a widget with pan gesture in PageView ,and the PageView can scoll horizontally,When I pan the widget horizontally,the PageView will move.

**What I expect is that the pan gesture can move the widget in the pageview,instead of moving the PageView**

Here is the picture.

[image]

Here is the demo code"

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return ChildPage(
            index: index,
          );
        },
        itemCount: 2,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const ChildPage({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChildPageState createState() => _ChildPageState();
}

class _ChildPageState extends State<ChildPage> {
  Offset offset = Offset.zero;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Positioned(
              top: offset.dy,
              left: offset.dx,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  print("hh");
                  offset = offset.translate(details.delta.dx, details.delta.dy);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                ),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do you like to change the page

Comment: and you can use `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),` at `PageViewBuilder` for not to scroll.

Comment: But I need this PageView scroll when my finger is in PageView but not in that widget @YeasinSheikh

Comment: lets'say you want gesture detector for both page and widget change on horizontal scroll ?

Comment: I have a solution,I use RawGestureDectector,and use Horizontal and Vertical gestures

Comment: Thx,It can work,but a little bit complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RawGestureDectector,and use Horizontal and Vertical gestures to avoid this solution